# name for the product of oscillation amplitude and frequency over spectral bandwidth

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density

In the field of signal processing, when a spectral peak is fitted with a Gaussian, is there a name for the quantity obtained by multiplying amplitude with frequency and dividing by the standard deviation (sigma) of the Gaussian?

It's meant to be a measure of oscillation strength.

I think I saw that quantity named something like "beta factor" or "beta coefficient" (but not exactly like that, albeit I'm quite sure "beta" was in the name) somewhere in neuroscience literature, and I can't remember where.

Comment: Interesting! I haven't heard of this. What context are you in? Communication signals in Doppler/Fading channels? Or more description of classical Oscillators? Or are you a physicist somewhere in quantum regime? Context very likely helps a lot when finding terms :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I read it in the neuroscience literature. I think it was referring to CPG (Central Pattern Generator) activity, neural circuits that generate rhythmic activity for rhythmic motor patterns such as locomotion, respiration, heartbeat, chewing, peristalsis, etc.

Comment: cool! Added that to your question! Absolutely not my area of expertise, sadly.